# Thread execution in sections

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class{

...

     method(x,y){

...

     method(x-1,y);  //own thread for recursion
     method(x,y-1);  //own thread for recursion
     }
}
```

I want to execute threaded code sections, how can i sign such sections in java.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the built in java facilities?  If you're on java 7, parallel recursion is easy:

[RecursiveTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html)

The javadocs contain a solution to the classic Fibonacci problem.

**UPDATE**
Here's an example for summing an array.  I don't claim it's the most efficient thing to put in a RecursiveTask, but it's a good example of how to use it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;


public class Sum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1548240649873455442L;
    private int arr[];
    private int hi;
    private int lo;

    public Sum(int arr[]) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.lo = 0;
        this.hi = arr.length-1;
    }

    private Sum(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.hi = hi;
        this.lo = lo;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        if (lo == hi) {
            return Long.valueOf(arr[lo]);
        }
        else {
            int mid = (hi+lo)/2;
            Sum sumleft = new Sum(arr, lo, mid);
            Sum sumright = new Sum(arr, mid+1, hi);
            sumleft.fork();
            return sumright.compute().longValue() + sumleft.join().longValue();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Sum sum = new Sum(arr);
        System.out.println(pool.invoke(sum));
    }

}
```

The big things to notice here:

1. You have to have a way to stop the recursion (in this example it's when you're summing only one element)
2. You should use .compute() for one side of your reduction, and then .fork() the other side, and use .join() to get it's value.

Comment: For methods sections like in my example?

Comment: ps: this is not the most efficient way to sum an array.  it would typically be faster to just loop through the array, but it's a good example of how to use the api.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with threading scenarios like this. The first impulse would be to write something like:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               method(x-1,y);
           }
       });
 Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               method(x,y-1);
           }
       });
 t1.start();
 t2.start();

 //...
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
```

This will do what you want, but unfortunately, since the method is recursive, the thread spawning will soon run out of control and oversubscribe the system, since threads will be spawned at each level of recursion.

You will need to set up a threshold and then switch to sequential calls one the threshold is hit:

```
 if(currentLevel < threshold) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  method(x-1,y,currentLevel + 1);
              }
          });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  method(x,y-1,currentLevel + 1);
              }
          });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    //...
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
 } else {
     method(x-1,y); 
     method(x,y-1); 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.